# How to check if 30 days have passed?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How to check if 30 days have passed since the user has first opened my app? After 30 days have passed, the app should do some things, for example: backup data, send mail etc.
The I would like to reset the 30 day timer to 0, and check again in 30 days.

Comment: Client side configurations are always weak to be hacked. You should try to ask your server these kind of information.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can do with the help of IsolatedStorageSettings. You can save first launch date in IsolatedStorageSettings Application_Launching.   add following in your App.xaml.cs, May this will help you

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings userSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
            //Save first launch date
            if (!userSettings.Contains("Date"))
            {
                userSettings.Add("Date", DateTime.Now.Date);
            }
            else
            {
                DateTime saveDate = Convert.ToDateTime(userSettings["Date"]);
                double days = (DateTime.Now.Date - saveDate).TotalDays;
                if (days > 30)
                {
                    //Do you work 
                    //remove userSettings for reset settings 
                    userSettings.Remove("Date");
                }
            }
        userSettings.Save();
    }
```

Comment: @user3409461  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79347/reminding-new-users-of-accept-upvote-duty http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21258/asking-upvote-for-accepted-answer go with links.

Comment: Will it go wrong if I change current date time in phone?

Answer (score 3):

You can use IsolatedStorageSettings to store key value pairs. Then on the app startup you can check the value and compare it to todays date and do whatever you want.

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

settings["somekey"] = "myvalue";
settings["otherkey"] = true;

settings.Save();
```

http://blog.rajenki.com/2013/01/local-and-roaming-storage-on-windows-8-and-windows-phone/

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the start time and date of the 30-day interval in a file using the IsolatedStorage.

The start date must be read when your app is loaded and compared with the current date and time. If that timespan is > 30 days, do your tasks, then store the current date as start of the interval.